# Xamarin ListView Adding/Removing Items is too slow

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a ListView that shows the Items of the current employee. When I click on my ToolBarItem I wanna show all Items. If I click The ToolBarItem again I only wanna show the Items of the current employee again.
My problem is that the Adding and Removing takes too long. Is there away to make that faster?

This is the Code that Adds and Removes the Items:

```
    private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (ToolbarItem.Text == "Andere Mitarbeiter")
        {
            ToolbarItem.Text = "Aktueller Mitarbeiter";
            if (TourPositionen.Count != AlleTourPositionen.Count)
            {
                foreach (var TourPos in AlleTourPositionen.Where(T => !TourPositionen.Contains(T)))
                {
                    TourPositionen.Add(TourPos);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ToolbarItem.Text = "Andere Mitarbeiter";
            foreach (var TourPos in AlleTourPositionen.Where(T => !T.Pause && T.Mitarbeiter != GlobalClass.AktuelleTour.Mitarbeiter))
            {
                TourPositionen.Remove(TourPos);
            } 
        }         
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with it takes too long? Is the app freezing or something else? What type is `TourPositionen`?

Comment: It might be faster to create a new collection, then set TourPositionen to it. `var newlist = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(); foreach ... { newlist.Add(TourPos); } TourPositionen = newlist;` This forces UI to update the entire ListView at once.

Comment: Cheesebaron TourPositionen is an ObservableCollection<TourPosition>

@ToolmakerSteve: That does not work. If you set the Collection to a new Collection the UI doesnt update at all...

Comment: Ok. I forgot that for view to see that the collection has been replaced, it has to have a special setter. Exact code depends on how you implement MVVM. Something like: `public ObservableCollection<TourPosition> TourPositionen { get => _tourPositionen; set => SetProperty(ref _tourPositionen, value);` with private field: `ObservableCollection<TourPosition> _tourPositionen = new ObservableCollection<TourPosition>();`. Change that to be similar to other dynamic properties you have. Then setting `TourPositionen =` to a new collection should work.

Comment: Use the Community Toolkit Observable Range collection ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.objectmodel.observablerangecollection-1?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk ) it will not fire a UI update for each single Add or Remove. But only once per block.

Comment: @Depechie didnt change much... But at least AddRange, RemoveRange and ReplaceRange save some lines of code :D